# Remove files from website and server with php

Tags: php, button, global-variables

I'm trying to make a private cloud storage-for fun

I have a php file with all the css js  with a fuction myFiles that generates divs with full name (example.xxx) image ( .xxx) with link do download file. i want to add a delete button that will be auto generated for each file on server in folder>UPLOADS.

And now i have 2 problems 
-how to make a variable for each file  like $a1 = example.xxx, $a2 $a3...
-and add that $a1 to a button somehow than return it to deleteIt.php so it can run unlink($a1)

```
function myFiles(){
$dir_path = "uploads";
if (is_dir($dir_path)) {
 if ($dh = opendir($dir_path)) {
     while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
         $target_file = $file . basename($FILES["codeName"]["name"]);
         $file_type = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
         if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'index.html' && $file_type != 'jpg' && $file_type != 'jpeg' && $file_type != 'gif' && $file_type != 'mp3' && $file_type != 'mp4' && $file_type != 'png'){
            $element = "<div class='entery-content' style='width:120px; min-height:130px;max-height:160px;float:left;margin-right:30px;padding-bottom:55px;'>
            <figure>    
                <a href='/application/views/uploads/$file' download><img src='/images/$file_type.png' class='icon'></a>     
                <figcaption style='text-align:center'>$file</figcaption>
            </figure>
            </div>";
            echo $element;
          }
      }
     closedir($dh);
 }
}
```

}

I have to add a button to delete it (under image) but like i said i'm lost.
I have some knowlage of php but not A LOT  and i'm gratefull for all the help i will get.

Comment: `<a href='/application/views/uploads/$file' download>` looks incorrect ( unless `download` is an attribute I'm unaware of )

Comment: instead of opening new page it can force file to download

Comment: I was unaware of that attribute

Comment: code here works  -delete :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with creating a new file for each element in folder uploads. That is in

**while loop** `(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)`

It's not the best solution and the most optimised one but it works-for now (untill upgrade) and it's php only

```
$myfile = fopen('./delete/'.$name_file . ".php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            $txt = "<?php function destruct()
            { 
                unlink('$name_file.php');
                unlink('../uploads/$file');
            }
            destruct(); header('Location:https://*************************************'); 
            exit;?>";
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
            fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is totally untested but might give an idea how you might proceed - however I have just seen your last comment but thought I'd post anyway.

```
function myFiles(){
    $dir_path = "uploads";
    if( is_dir( $dir_path ) ) {
        if ( $dh = opendir( $dir_path ) ) {
            while( ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) !== false ) {


                $target_file = $file . basename($FILES["codeName"]["name"]);
                $file_type = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


                if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != 'index.html' && $file_type != 'jpg' && $file_type != 'jpeg' && $file_type != 'gif' && $file_type != 'mp3' && $file_type != 'mp4' && $file_type != 'png'){

                $element = "
                <div class='entery-content' style='width:120px; min-height:130px; max-height:160px; float:left; margin-right:30px; padding-bottom:55px;'>
                    <figure>    
                        <a href='/application/views/uploads/$file' download>
                            <img src='/images/$file_type.png' class='icon'>
                        </a>

                        <input type='button' value='Delete' />

                        <figcaption style='text-align:center'>$file</figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </div>";


                echo $element;
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
        }
    }
}



<script>
    var url='delete.php';
    var col=Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('figure > a > input[type="button"]') );
    col.forEach( function( bttn ){
        bttn.onlick=function(e){
            var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )alert( xhr.response );
                };
                xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( 'file='+this.querySelector('a > img').src );
        }.bind( bttn.parentNode );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: walk me through - i just add that code to my site and it will work. See i know php c++ c# python3 but i don't know anything about js becouse i'm 16 years old.... (Started programing like 2 years ago

Comment: and how can i add it to unlink(____what variable here___); in delete.php